# Link without www redirects me to a different page

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

I have a link that if written as `www.myLink.example/myPage` takes me to the good page. If I have just `myLink.example/myPage` it takes me to myLink.example, and doesn't save the `/myPage` part. my `.htaccess` looks like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: What happens when you request `http://www.myLink.example/myPage` (note the "http")? Check the HTTP headers of the redirect response and paste them in your question. If you change the redirect status to 302, does it change the response? You'll need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: ... and is that all you have in your `.htaccess` file?